# Recursivley return an arrayList of specific indexes

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

As the title suggests, I am trying to recursively return an arrayList of Student objects that have a gpa higher than 3.5. Here is my attempt at this.

```
public static ArrayList<Student> honorsStudents(Student[] list, int n) {
    ArrayList<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    if (n == 0) {
        return studentsList;
    } else {
        boolean currentIsHonors = list[n - 1].isHonors();
        if (currentIsHonors) {
            studentsList.add(list[n - 1]);
            return honorsStudents(list, n - 1);
        } else {
            return honorsStudents(list, n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

isHonors() of course determines whether or not the gpa is greater than 3.5. 
Not sure where exactly I'm screwing this up.

My method is not returning a null arrayList. Not catching any indexes with GPA's greater than 3.5.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: uh, my method is not returning an arraylist of student objects with gpas greater than 3.5. I'll clarify in my post. @tnw

Comment: does it HAVE to be recursive?

Comment: Ok, then what *does* it return? This seems needlessly complicated. Why aren't you just doing a simple `for` loop?

Comment: Yes it has to be recursive @kwikness

Comment: It retuns a null arrayList, with a size of 0. This is a class assignment  that I have been banging my head against the wall over. I don't understand how my logic is wrong, it has to be recursive. @tnw

Comment: Welcome to the homework zone.

Comment: Why it is recursive? And what is the value of n initially?

Comment: Its a homework assignement, and n is the lists size @Sarz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new list with each recursive call:

```
 ArrayList<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

You need to create this list outside of the function:

```
static ArrayList<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student>();


public static ArrayList<Student> honorsStudents(Student[] list, int n)
{

    if (n==0)
    {
        return studentsList;
    }       
    else
    {
        boolean currentIsHonors = list[n-1].isHonors();
        if(currentIsHonors)
        {
            studentsList.add(list[n-1]);
            return honorsStudents(list, n-1);
        }
        else 
        {
            return honorsStudents(list, n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Making it `static` means that you have to reset after every use of this method if you want to do it again.  Passing the `List` in the recursive invocation is almost certainly better practice.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new `ArrayList` within each method iteration.  This will never work recursively because you need to be adding elements to the *same* list.

Consider having a base method that starts off your recursion using a blank list, then pass that *same* list for each iteration of the recursion:

```
//This method takes in the initial values and starts the actual recursion
public static ArrayList<Student> honorsStudents(Student[] list, int n)
{
    return honorStudents(list, n, new ArrayList<Student>());
}

//this is the actual recursive method
public static ArrayList<Student> honorsStudents(Student[] list, int n, List<Student> studentsList)
{
    if (n==0)
    {
        return studentsList;
    }       
    else
    {
        boolean currentIsHonors = list[n-1].isHonors();
        if(currentIsHonors)
        {
            studentsList.add(list[n-1]);
            return honorsStudents(list, n-1, studentsList);
        }
        else 
        {
            return honorsStudents(list, n-1, studentsList);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this piece of code, I don't think you need recursive method

```
public static ArrayList<Student> honorsStudents(Student[] list, int n) {
            ArrayList<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            if (n==0)
            {
            System.out.println("END");
                return studentsList;
            }       
        for(Student s: list{
            if(s.isHonors()){
                studentsList.add(s);
            }
        }
        return studentsList; //all students with isHonors == true
    }
```

Comment: Of course it is possible to do it non-recursively but read the requirements of the question.